# Prove that $\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}=\pm\tan\frac{\beta}{2}\tan\frac{\gamma}{2}$ based on given condition

Tags: trigonometry

> If $$\cos\alpha=\cos\beta\cos\phi=\cos\gamma\cos\theta$$
>   and $$\sin\alpha=2\sin\frac{\phi}{2}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$$
>   then prove that $$\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}=\pm\tan\frac{\beta}{2}\tan\frac{\gamma}{2}$$

My approach:

$$\frac{\cos \alpha}{\cos\beta}=\cos\phi$$
$$=1-2\sin^2\frac{\phi}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow 2\sin^2\frac{\phi}{2}=1-\frac{\cos\alpha}{\cos\beta}$$
and(in the similar fashion)
$$\Rightarrow 2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}=1-\frac{\cos\alpha}{\cos\gamma}$$

Please help me to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin^2\alpha=2\sin^2\dfrac\phi2\cdot2\sin^2\dfrac\theta2$$

$$=\left(1-\frac{\cos\alpha}{\cos\beta}\right)\left(1-\frac{\cos\alpha}{\cos\gamma}\right)$$

$$\cos\beta\cos\gamma(1-\cos^2\alpha)=(\cos\beta-\cos\alpha)(\cos\gamma-\cos\alpha)$$

$$-\cos^2\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma=-\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\cos\gamma+\cos^2\alpha$$

Assuming $\cos\alpha\ne0,$

$$-\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma=-\cos\beta-\cos\gamma+\cos\alpha$$

$$\iff\cos\alpha(1+\cos\beta\cos\gamma)=\cos\beta+\cos\gamma$$

$$\dfrac{\cos\beta+\cos\gamma}{1+\cos\beta\cos\gamma}=\dfrac{\cos\alpha}1$$

Apply [Componendo and Dividendo](http://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Junior%20Secondary/Componendo%20et%20Dividendo.htm) and use $$\cos2x=\dfrac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}$$